# Get drupal breadcrumb by providing nid?

Tags: 7

How can I get a breadcrumb path by providing `$nid`?

Example

```
$nid = 116;
$breadcrumb = breadcrumb_get_crumb($nid);
```

I have a node type that is always associated with another node, and I want to use that node's breadcrumb trail for this node too.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Crumbs](http://drupal.org/project/crumbs) module.
Now, if you say these nodes are "associated", I wonder how exactly? With an [Entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field? Or just that you know the parent? Is this for all nodes of this type, or just for this specific one? Are these nodes somewhere in a menu?

If you can arrange either of the criteria above, you can use existing Crumbs plugins. Otherwise, you could do a custom module..

Answer (score 0):

sounds to me that you could use the [Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) module, just set those node types custom breadcrumbs to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a function to retrieve this information. It loops through the menu structure several times and builds a array with the needed info.

```
function getBreadcrumbs($menu)
{

    $menu = @menu_load_links($menu);
    $breadcrumbs = array();
    $parentSearch = -1;

    // check 10 levels back from the current page, back to the highest page
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        // stop when the item with no parent is found
        if ($parentSearch === 0) {
            continue;
        }
        // loop the menu for this level check
        foreach($menu as $item) {
            $link = url($item['link_path']);
            if ($link === url(current_path()) && $parentSearch === -1) {
                $breadcrumbs[] = array('title' => $item['link_title'], 'url' => $link, 'current' => true, 'mlid' => $item['mlid']);
                $parentSearch = (int) $item['plid'];
            } else if ($parentSearch !== -1 && (int) $item['mlid'] === $parentSearch) {
                $breadcrumbs[] = array('title' => $item['link_title'], 'url' => $link, 'current' => false, 'mlid' => $item['mlid']);
                $parentSearch = (int) $item['plid'];
            }
        }
    }

    return array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
}
```