# Generate breadcrumb based on a given Path

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

How can I know the breadcrumb that will be generated in a page without visiting that page? Is this possible?

Comment: This similar question may help you on your quest: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11325/get-drupal-breadcrumb-by-providing-nid

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what module/configuration you are using to generate the breadcrumb, sometimes some basic configuration is set in the base theme you are using as well, you might wanna check that out in your `page.tpl.php` file. basically your question is so vague it's hard to answer.

but mostly in most of themes the breadcrumb is being generated like this:

```
Home > Node title

Home > Taxonomy Term > Node title
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but if you want full control over your breadcrumbs (so that you can predict what the breadcrumb will be at a given path), take a look at Crumbs (https://www.drupal.org/project/crumbs) or Path Breadcrumbs (https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs)

Both modules will allow you to define rules/criteria that are used to construct the breadcrumbs you want on your site.

Comment: In addition, with Crumbs you can go to admin/structure/crumbs/debug, and see the breadcrumb generated with a path of your choice.